# Please someone tell me the name of this algebra trick or where I can learn how to do it..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, control-theory

Okay so my algebra knowledge is pretty guff..

I am taking a control systems class and pretty much all the questions I am expected to revise, are about doing this algebraic manipulation and I don't know what steps the tutor is taking to do it..

Okay here goes..

If the transfer function of a system is $G(s) = 3/(20s+1)$, then the closed loop version of that is

$$G(s)/(G(s) + 1)$$

so that would be

$$\frac{\frac{3}{20s+1}}{\frac{3}{20s+1} + 1}$$

This is the bit I am having trouble with.. he just then cancels it all out and gives us the answer on the next line which is.. $$\frac{3}{20s+4}$$

He gives us loads of problems to this which are all similar but I just cannot work them out as my algebra sucks so bad.. I don't know how to cancel out stuff which has a division but with an addition in the denominator..

I have taken a screen shot of the pdf here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKpxh.png

[And another one of another pdf which explains nearly how to do it but misses out the steps..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o44WR.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac {\frac 3{20s+1}}{\frac3{20s+1}+1}=\frac {\frac 3{20s+1}}{\frac3{20s+1}+1}\cdot\frac {20s+1}{20s+1}=\frac{3}{3+20s+1}=\frac 3{20s+4}$$

Comment: Thankyou so much it makes sense so obviously when someone puts it like this

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{3}{20s+1}}{\frac{3}{20s+1}+1} &= \frac{{20s+1}}{{20s+1}}\frac{\frac{3}{20s+1}}{\frac{3}{20s+1}+1}\\
& = \frac{\frac{3(20s+1)}{20s+1}}{\frac{3(20s+1)}{20s+1}+(20s+1)}\\
& = \frac{3}{3+(20s+1)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Multiply nominator and denominator by $20s+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually resort to doing everything straightforwardly if you don't see how the "tricks" work.

In this case, the straightforward thing is to "compute" the sum:

$$ \frac{3}{20s + 1} + 1 = \frac{20s + 4}{20s+1} $$

There are lots of ways to see how to do this. You can try to find the least common denominator, but it's good enough to find *any* common denominator. i.e. you can write

$$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad}{bd} + \frac{bc}{bd} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd} $$

Once you've done that, the next straightforward thing to do is to divide fractions. There are again several mnemonics for remembering this; a common one is

$$ \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c} = \frac{ad}{bc} $$

Comment: Thankyou so much for putting the effort in I get it now!